# Passing data with override func prepare using collectionviewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uistoryboardsegue

I am trying to send the charName String from AvengersViewController to CharViewController.

I am using a collection view in AvengersViewController. CharName is a label in CharViewController.

What I am trying works perfectly with a table view but I can't get it to work using collectionViews...

I am using "lastItemSelectedA" to indicate the index of the label from my avengers array. The passing of data works... I can't get the index of the collectionViewItem to pass with the first segue, thus, making it null. By using the default value of 0 I have been able to notice that it does work, however, it does not change the value of lastItemSelectedA when the cell is pressed but after... Or at least it does not update the variable.

I have already tried at least 5 implementations from solutions on stack.

```
extension AvengersViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        lastItemSelectedA = indexPath.item
        //self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "openToCharA", sender: indexPath.item)
    }
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        guard let identifier = segue.identifier else { return }

        switch identifier {
        case "openToCharA":


            if let destination = segue.destination as? CharViewController {
                destination.charName = avengers[lastItemSelectedA ?? 0].name
            }

            //destination.sounds = sounds
            //guard let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems else {return}
            //let sounds = fallen[lastItemSelectedF!].sounds

        default:
            print("unexpected segue identifier")
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `prepare(for segue` is called then you've connected the segue from the collection view **cell** (rather than from the **controller**).

In this case delete

```
var lastItemSelectedA : Int
```

and

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    lastItemSelectedA = indexPath.item
    //self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "openToCharA", sender: indexPath.item)
}
```

and get the index path of the collection view cell from the `sender` parameter

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "openToCharA" {
        let cell = sender as! UICollectionViewCell
        let indexPath = collectionView.indexPath(for: cell)!
        let destination = segue.destination as! CharViewController
        destination.charName = avengers[indexPath.item].name
    }
}
```

Force unwrapping the optionals is fine in this case. The code must not crash if everything is hooked up correctly and if it does it reveals a **design** mistake.

Comment: where do i define identifier and indexPath? shouldn't I leave the didSelectIteamAt func?

Comment: My bad, it's `segue.identifier`. `didSelectItemAt` is not needed as the you get the indexPath from the cell.

Comment: okay... I am still getting an error in "let indexPath = indexPath(for:cell)", tells me I am using a variable within its own value

Comment: Please see my edit, `collectionView` is the `collectionView` instance

Comment: works perfectly... So I know use the specific cells as an  index is that correct?

Comment: Yeah, this is a better solution. I'm going to remove mine.

Comment: Once again, when you tap a collection view cell, `prepare(for` is called and the tapped cell is passed in the `sender` parameter. With `indexPath(for` you can get the index path of the cell.